# Airflow 2 Push Xcom with Key Name

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

In Airflow 2 taskflow API I can, using the following code examples, easily push and pull XCom values between tasks:-

```
@task(task_id="task_one")
    def get_height() -> int:
        response = requests.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/4")
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        height = int(data["height"])
        return height

    @task(task_id="task_two")
    def check_height(val):
        # Show val:
        print(f"Value passed in is: {val}")

    check_height(get_height())
```

I can see that the val passed into check_height is 202 and is wrapped in the xcom default key 'return_value' and that's fine for some of the time, but I generally prefer to use specific keys.

My question is how can I push the XCom with a named key? This was really easy previously with ti.xcom_push where you could just supply the key name you wanted the value to be stuffed into, but I can't quite put my finger on how to achieve this in the taskflow api workflow.

Would appreciate any pointers or (simple, please!) examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set `ti` in the decorator as:

```
@task(task_id="task_one", ti)
def get_height() -> int:
    response = requests.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/4")
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    height = int(data["height"])

    # Handle named Xcom
    ti.xcom_push("my_key", height)
```

For cases where you need context in deep function you can also use `get_current_context`. I'll use it in my example below just to show it but it's not really required in your case.

here is a working example:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

import requests

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context

DEFAULT_ARGS = {"owner": "airflow"}


@dag(dag_id="stackoverflow_dag", default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS, schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime(2020, 2, 2))
def my_dag():

    @task(task_id="task_one")
    def get_height() -> int:
        response = requests.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/4")
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        height = int(data["height"])

        # Handle named Xcom
        context = get_current_context()
        ti = context["ti"]
        ti.xcom_push("my_key", height)

        return height

    @task(task_id="task_two")
    def check_height(val):
        # Show val:
        print(f"Value passed in is: {val}")

        #Read from named Xcom
        context = get_current_context()
        ti = context["ti"]
        ti.xcom_pull("task_one")
        print(f"Value passed from xcom my_key is: {val}")

    check_height(get_height())

my_dag = my_dag()
```

two xcoms being pushed (one for the returned value and one with the by the key we choose):
[image]

printing the two xcoms in downstream `task_two`:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh.... so with the taskflow API we can still use Xcom push and pull methods by driving ti from the context object? That's really excellent - thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much, I had a similar issue that your scripting solved